# Logarithmic Complex Line Integral

Tags: logarithms, complex-integration, line-integrals, multivalued-functions

Compute the integral $\int_\gamma log z \,dz$ where you need to select a continuous branch of the logarithm based on the given value of the logarithm at one of the points on $\gamma$:

1- $\gamma$ is the unit circle |$z$|$=1$ oriented counterclockwise and started at $z=1$, and $ log( 1)=0$.

2- $\gamma$ is the unit circle |$z$|$=1$ oriented counterclockwise and started at $z=i$, and $ log( i)=\pi i/2$.

I doubt that my solution is correct because I didn't use the given information of the logarithmic 1 and i.

**My attempt:**

I use for both cases a cut at the origin point.

Part 1:

$z=e^{i \theta}$

$\int_0^{2\pi} log (e^{i \theta}) i e^{i \theta} \,d\theta$ = $\int_0^{2\pi} {i \theta} i e^{i \theta} \,d\theta$ = - $\int_0^{2\pi} {\theta} e^{i \theta} \,d\theta$ = $2\pi i$

Part 2:

$\int_{\pi/2}^{2\pi} log (e^{i \theta}) i e^{i \theta} \,d\theta$ + $\int_0^{\pi/2} log e^{i \theta + 2i\pi} i e^{i \theta} \,d\theta$

Comment: Don't you mean in the second case starting at $z=i$?

Comment: Yes sorry, I will edit it now ! thanks

Comment: log$(z)$ is going to have a branch cut _somewhere_ in the complex plane. It seems that the question is asking for you to choose a branch where one of the points is defined, on said branch. So for the first one, an appropriate branch choice would be the branch $[0,2\pi]$. Can you guess what the appropriate branch choice for the second one would be?

Comment: Hint: In order to integrate along a contour that involves a branch cut, you need to show that the value of the function exists at the point on the branch cut. Knowing this, do you feel that you've used the given information?